# Open excel file with url in vba code error

Tags: excel, vba

Using a link "https://~" that downloads excel file from web, the following code was tried.

```
Workbooks.Open("https://~")
```

Just copy and pasting the url link in any web browser works fine - downloads excel file with all the contents intact.

However, with the above vba link, an excel file opens in [read only] format and completely blank even without the vertical and horizontal lines in excel.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because your file is not stored in your pc (only as a temp file).

You need to `SaveAs` the file after you open it from web.

```
Sub SaveFile()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("https://yoururl.com/yourfile.xls")
    wb.SaveAs ("C:\yourPath\SavedFile.xls", FileFormat:=56)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but the same problem occurs

Comment: Can you show your code? Works fine with me.

Comment: I don't think I can share the url link as this is corporate... Thank you I will try other methods and see how they work.

Comment: I am not asking you for url link. I am asking for rest of the code (or at least that SaveAs part).

Comment: That is the entire code `Sub test() ~ End Sub`

Comment: You stated "Thanks but the same problem occurs" after I suggested you SaveAs - I suppose you tried it.

Comment: I see that from the url - downloads excel 97-2003 worksheet - this could be the issue?

Comment: Apologies, I thought you meant saving the excel file used to write the vba code which I have tried. Before I just opened a random temp file and ran the code. And I tried saving the file with the code and running the vba code.

Comment: Of course saving downloaded file. Please try and let know.

Comment: have tried `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ("downloadedfile.xls")`  And the same problem occurs. But when I open the saved file, I get an error message "The file format and extension of 'downloadedfile.xls' don't match". If I just click ok, it opens a blank file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226872/discussion-between-michal-palko-and-jh-y).